# is there a way to see logging after hitting Menu button on iPhone simulator then relaunching the app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios-simulator, xcode4

Is there a way in XCode4 / iPhone Simulator to see logging coming from the application after you have stopped and re-started the app on the simulator?

That is:

- start app on simulator in debug mode (logging appears in XCode4 fine)
- push menu button on simulator
- go to app menu on the simulator and press the icon for the application
- application starts again, but no logging to be seen in XCode4??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press the Home Button, the app is just suspend in the background. If you mark any section of code with [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a), it will complete before suspending. When you launch the app again from the Springboard, Xcode is still connected to the same process. Make sure you don't stop the debugger when press the Home button.

Check you Info.plist for the following key: **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend**. For additional information search for section *Opting Out of Background Execution* in [The Core Application Design](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW24) doc. If the **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** is set to **YES**, your app will terminate.

Comment: I've just noticed that I did have "Application does not run in background" set to NO.  I changed this to YES but noted after this my app no longer seemed to call "applicationWillTerminate" where I have been doing the core data "saveContext"...so I've broken some of the existing functionality by switching this flag...will keep digging